Java Swing drawing gif as background to several JButtons and JLabels
I want to draw a gif as background to the starting window of my java project (small game in Java swing for school). Here's my code so far:
package graphic;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;

//Frame di inizio gioco usato per la selezione del numero di giocatori e la modalità di gioco
public class selectionWindow extends JFrame {

    //Panelli
    private final JPanel logoPanel = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel selectionPanel = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel offlinePanel = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel onlinePanel = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel foregroundPanel = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel backgroundPanel = new JPanel();
    //Componenti offline
    private final JButton offlineButton = new JButton("Offline");
    private final JButton offlineButton_twoPlayer = new JButton("2 Players");
    private final JButton offlineButton_threePlayer = new JButton("3 Players");
    private final JButton offlineButton_fourPlayer = new JButton("4 Players");
    private final Component[] offlineComponents;
    //Componenti online
    private final JButton onlineButton = new JButton("Online");
    private final JButton onlineButton_twoPlayer = new JButton("2 Players");
    private final JButton onlineButton_threePlayer = new JButton("3 Players");
    private final JButton onlineButton_fourPlayer = new JButton("4 Players");
    private final JButton joinButton = new JButton("Join Game");
    private final Component[] onlineComponents;;
    //Immagine decoration
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon( "graphics"+File.separator+"decoration"+File.separator+"BombermanLogo.png");
    JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(imageIcon);
    //Immagine di sfondo
    ImageIcon backgroundGIF = new ImageIcon("graphics"+File.separator+"decoration"+File.separator+"background.gif");
    JLabel backgroundLabel = new JLabel(backgroundGIF);
    //Font
    Font pixelFont;

    public selectionWindow(){  // ForegroundPanel contiene logoPanel e selectionPanel ed ha un layout a griglia 2x1
        //Caratteristiche e comportamento della frame
        super("BomberMan Game");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        //this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        // Posiziona la finestra al centro dello schermo
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //Background Panel
        backgroundPanel.add(backgroundLabel);
        this.add(backgroundPanel);
        //this.setComponentZOrder(backgroundPanel, 1);

        //Foreground Panel
        foregroundPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        foregroundPanel.add(logoPanel);
        foregroundPanel.add(selectionPanel);
        this.add(foregroundPanel);
        //this.setComponentZOrder(backgroundPanel, 0);

        //JPanel per la decorazione
        logoPanel.add(logoLabel);

        //JPanel per la selezione
        selectionPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        selectionPanel.add(offlinePanel);
        selectionPanel.add(onlinePanel);

        //JPanel per la selezione offline
        offlinePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(offlinePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        offlinePanel.add(offlineButton);
        offlinePanel.add(offlineButton_twoPlayer);
        offlinePanel.add(offlineButton_threePlayer);
        offlinePanel.add(offlineButton_fourPlayer);
        //Centrare gli elementi nel pannello (perchè il box layout altrimenti li allinea a sinistra)
        offlineButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        offlineButton_twoPlayer.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        offlineButton_threePlayer.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        offlineButton_fourPlayer.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        offlineComponents = offlinePanel.getComponents(); //Lista dei componenti del panello offline (viene poi utilizzata per i listener)

        //JPanel per la selezione online
        onlinePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(onlinePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        onlinePanel.add(onlineButton);
        onlinePanel.add(onlineButton_twoPlayer);
        onlinePanel.add(onlineButton_threePlayer);
        onlinePanel.add(onlineButton_fourPlayer);
        onlinePanel.add(joinButton);
        //Centrare gli elementi nel pannello (perchè il box layout altrimenti li allinea a sinistra)
        onlineButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        onlineButton_twoPlayer.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        onlineButton_threePlayer.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        onlineButton_fourPlayer.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        joinButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        onlineComponents = onlinePanel.getComponents(); //Lista dei componenti del panello online (viene poi utilizzata per i listener)

        //Carica il font
        pixelFont = new pixelFont().getPixelFont();

        //Gestione componenti offline
        offlineActionListener offlineAL = new offlineActionListener(offlineComponents,onlineComponents, this); ;
        for (Component component : offlineComponents){
            JButton button = (JButton) component;
            if (button != offlineButton) { //Escludo il bottone offline perchè deve rimanere sempre visibile e attivo
                button.setVisible(false);
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }
            button.setFont(pixelFont);
            button.setContentAreaFilled(false); //Rimuove il background del bottone
            button.setBorderPainted(false); //Rimuove il bordo del bottone
            button.addActionListener(offlineAL);
        }

        //Gestione componenti online
        onlineActionListener onlineAL = new onlineActionListener(onlineComponents,offlineComponents, this); ;
        for (Component component : onlineComponents){
            JButton button = (JButton) component;
            if (button != onlineButton) { //Escludo il bottone online perchè deve rimanere sempre visibile e attivo
                button.setVisible(false);
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }
            button.setFont(pixelFont);
            button.setContentAreaFilled(false); //Rimuove il background del bottone
            button.setBorderPainted(false); //Rimuove il bordo del bottone
            button.addActionListener(onlineAL);
        }
        //Modifica icona della finestra
        this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("graphics"+File.separator+"decoration"+File.separator+"icon.png").getImage());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        selectionWindow window = new selectionWindow();
    }
}




I tried to use a JLayeredPane and the method setComponentZOrder but i can't manage to make them work, what am i missing?
I'm 100% sure all the addresses are right (if i comment this.add(foregroundPanel) the gif is correctly shown).
Thanks for any responses <3
I tried to use a JLayeredPane and the method setComponenetZOrder (in those cases i would also add foregroundPanel.setOpaque(false)), expecting them organize the window in such a way so all the contents of foregroundPanel were visible and the gif would play in the background without overlapping any other components.
I tried to implement them in many different ways, sometimes completely changing the structure of the GUI but i always got the same  two results: only one of the panels was visible or the backgroundPanel would be above the foregroundPanel and i only could see the buttons for a split second when i hovered my mouse over them.
Thanks for the answers (it's my first question on this platform so i don't really know how to use it), I really appreciate them but there seems to be a missunderstanding.
My goal was to combine the contents of backgroundPanel, which should look something like this: [backgroundPanelContent]: (https://i.sstatic.net/1PPV2r3L.gif)
and the contents of foregroundPanel, which should look something like this:
[foregroundPanelContent]: (https://i.sstatic.net/Qs66gmdn.png)
to make a frame similar to this:[result]: (https://i.sstatic.net/6qY1nVBM.gif)
(Sorry for bad photoshop i threw it together in a few minutes)

Don't do this this.add(backgroundPanel). Instead, do this.getContentPane().add(backgroundPanel). Even if this doesn't work, this is the correct way to add your main panel to the JFrame.

I am not sure, but I think that you need to put the GIF in the foreground panel and whatever is in the foreground panel on the background panel. Even if you do this, I think you need to follow my advise on using a Layout Manager (see my answer).

You can use the GridBagLayout to stack to components on top of one another on the Z axis. The trick is to:

add both components to the same grid
add the components in the reverse order you want them painted

Simple example:
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagStack extends JPanel
{
    public GridBagStack()
    {
        setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        JPanel foreground = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        foreground.setOpaque(false);
        foreground.add( new JButton("Button1") );
        foreground.add( new JButton("Button2") );
        add(foreground, gbc);

        JLabel background = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("???.jpg") );
        add(background, gbc);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagStack");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new GridBagStack() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowUI() );
    }
}


Thanks a lot for the answer, in the end i used a overlayLayout and that worked perfectly.
Have a good night

The reason why it's not showing is because you are putting the foregroundPanel right on top. You are calling this this.add(backgroundPanel); then a few lines after, you are calling this this.add(foregroundPanel);
//Background Panel
backgroundPanel.add(backgroundLabel);
this.add(backgroundPanel);
//this.setComponentZOrder(backgroundPanel, 1);

//Foreground Panel
foregroundPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
foregroundPanel.add(logoPanel);
foregroundPanel.add(selectionPanel);
this.add(foregroundPanel); // you just placed this panel over your background panel

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this is definitely wrong. It would be nice if you could provide an illustration in your comments or explain your goal a bit better.
Also, as a general practice, you should put your main panel in the JFrame's content pane instead of directly into the JFrame. For example:
this.getContentPane().add(backgroundPanel)

One thing you can try is to place the background and foreground panels into another panel. Then, use a Layout Manager in the container panel to control how these two panels are to be laid out and lastly, put the container panel in the JFrame's content pane as I showed here.
EDIT: I also think that the GIF should be in the foreground and what you currently have as foreground needs to be the background. For example, if you are trying to represent a picture frame, the picture needs to be on the top-most layer (the foreground). Then, what constitutes the picture frame needs to be under the picture. Kind of like this
---------------------
|    background     |
|   -------------   |
|   |     0     |   |
|   |    \|/    |   |
|   |     |     |   |
|   |     |     |   |
|   |    / \    |   |
|   |foreground |   |
|   -------------   |
|                   |
---------------------

Again, I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but this is what I understood from your question.

Also, as a general practice, you should put your main panel in the JFrame's content pane instead of directly into the JFrame. - the add(...) method of the JFrame will add components to the content pane. There is no need to use getContentPane() first.

@camickr Thanks. I've always done that. I'm sure I read it somewhere. I guess you can't trust everything you read on the Internet. LOL. Aside from that, do you agree with the rest of my post? I think he needs to reverse his foreground and background (as a matter of principle based on the naming he used), then use a layout manager that would produce my crude drawing.

The layout managers documented in the tutorial are all 2D layout managers, so you can't stack components on top of one another. To have the foreground stacked on top of the background you can use the OverlayLayout, but the alignment of the two panels is not great unless you want them centered. The other option is to use the Swing parent/child relationship. So you would have frame - > content pane > background > foreground. The trick is to add a layout manager to the label used as the background. This will only work if the foreground component is smaller in size than the background image.

My understanding is that he wants the label as the background with a transparent panel containing component as the foreground.

@camickr "The trick is to add a layout manager to the label used as the background. This will only work if the foreground component is smaller in size than the background image." This is why I drew that picture. It was easier for me to convey that idea. This is what I thought he wanted to do. What I didn't consider, and it's a great point, was the "transparent panel" point you made on your second comment.

@camickr Thanks for the tip, my idea for the project was to have two panels of identical size overlayed on one another, with the top panel having transparent areas so that the contents of the lower panel would be visible. (As you said in a comments but i wanted to clarify).
Thanks again to both for replies, i will immediatly try applying them

so you can't stack components on top of one another. - actually you can use the GridBagLayout to stack components on top of one another, although it may not be apparent from the documentation. See my answer.

@shōgun for future reference, camickr is the authority on everything Java Swing. Whenever you have a Java Swing issue, search here for his answers. Back when I worked on Swing stuff ages ago, that's what I did.
